# How do I include custom fields of an entry type in the Guest Entries form?

Tags: guest-entries

I want any visitor to be able to submit links to my blog via the Guest Entries plugin, but how do I include the custom fields of my "Links" entry type in the Guest Entries form? For example, a category field, text fields...

Comment: OT: Rafael, do yourself a favor and get the client license. Entry types is definitely no useful solution to separate blog entries, a designer directory and user submitted links. Or is this "Links" entry type in fact one type of your blog entries?

Comment: Yep it is ;) Links will be part of the main blog page!

Answer (score 3):

if you're using an [Entry Form - [entries/saveEntry]](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form) you'll need to pass them in as fields.

For example if you had a text field called "Links" you would need an input like this

```
<input type="text" name="fields[links]" value="{{ entry.links }}">
```

Passing in inputs with the name fields[your_field_name] allow it to be picked up and populated correctly.